# How can you determine who's playing a game with who using the API?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to have my bot track activity of various users on the server. I currently have it capable of tracking how long someone plays what game, but it can't tell if the user is playing multiplayer/who with.

I've looked in the API documentation and the closest I've found was `activity.details` and `activity.party`, both of which had fairly sparse documentation, and neither of which I have been able to yield any data. Ideally it would look something along the lines of

```
aync def on_member_update(before, after):
    string_containing_group_of_players = after.activity.details
    # or
    string_containting_group_of_players = after.activity.party
```

I know discord has this information stored somewhere as I can see it if I go to home->activity, theres sometimes boxes of Recently Played or Now Playing, but I cannot for the life of me find where it is stored in the API. Any help (including links to docs I'm missing) would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I looked in the API and indeed it should be one of those, either `details` or `party`. I empathise the word should. Do note that even if there is that information there you're using `on_member_update` which will check for every member update, even those who aren't playing anything. And even if they are playing anything that game itself needs to support Discord rich presence for party info.